# Query with multiple PIVOT columns, different names and aggregated

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2016

I have the following CTE table called `assets` (please keep in mind that the number of accounts and ISINs is in the dozens & hundreds):

```
+---------------------------+---------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------+----------------------+------------------+--------+
|           Date            | Account |      ISIN      |      Quantity       |       Value        | Currency | Price                | PriceCHF         | FXRate |
+---------------------------+---------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------+----------------------+------------------+--------+
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       1 | CH5055181629   | 0.00000000          | 0.000000           | CHF      | 1124.56              | 1124.56          | 1      |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       6 | CH5055181629   | 0.37866100          | 425.827014         | CHF      | 1124.56              | 1124.56          | 1      |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       7 | CH5055181629   | 0.67151800          | 755.162282         | CHF      | 1124.56              | 1124.56          | 1      |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       8 | CH5055181629   | 0.45240000          | 508.750944         | CHF      | 1124.56              | 749.7067         | 1.5    |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       9 | CH5055181622   | 0.02204500          | 24.790925          | CHF      | 1124.56              | 749.7067         | 1.5    |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |      10 | CH5055181622   | 0.08353300          | 93.937870          | CHF      | 1124.56              | 749.7067         | 1.5    |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |      11 | CH5055181622   | 0.89667100          | 1008.360340        | CHF      | 1124.56              | 749.7067         | 1.5    |
+---------------------------+---------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+----------+----------------------+------------------+--------+
```

I want to dynamically change the columns based on the ISIN. Currently, I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
INTO   #assets 
FROM   (SELECT xxx 
        FROM   yyyy) a 

DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(max), 
        @query AS NVARCHAR(max); 

SET @cols = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(c.ISIN) 
                   FROM   #assets c 
                   FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '' 
            ) 
SET @query = 'SELECT date, account, ' + @cols 
             + ' from #assets x pivot ( max(quantity) for ISIN in (' + @cols 
             + ')) p ' 

EXECUTE(@query) 

DROP TABLE #assets
```

The result is a table with the Date, Account and each column per ISIN has the quantity value. Each associated quantity row from the original query has its quantity value in the field and the other `ISIN` columns are `NULL`.

Now, I want to have the columns be more than just the quantity. I want the name of the column to be, e.g. `ISIN + '_quantity'` and `ISIN + '_value'`.
Furthermore, I want the quantity values not be individually for each row, but *aggregated* per `Date` and `Account`.

So, my current result is the following:

```
+---------------------------+---------+--------------+----------------+
|           Date            | Account | CH5055181629 | CH5055181622   |
+---------------------------+---------+--------------+----------------+
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       1 | 0.000000     | NULL           |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       6 | 0.378661     | NULL           |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       7 | 0.671518     | NULL           |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       8 | 0.452400     | NULL           |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       9 | 0.000000     | NULL           |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |      10 | 0.000000     | NULL           |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |      11 | 0.000000     | NULL           |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       1 | NULL         | 0.000000       |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       6 | NULL         | 0.000000       |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       7 | NULL         | 0.000000       |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       8 | NULL         | 0.000000       |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       9 | NULL         | 0.022045       |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |      10 | NULL         | 0.083533       |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |      11 | NULL         | 0.896671       |
+---------------------------+---------+--------------+----------------+
```

My desired result would now be the following:

```
+---------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|           Date            | Account | CH5055181629_quantity | CH5055181622_quantity | CH5055181629_value | CH5055181622_value |
+---------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       1 | 0.000000              | 0.000000              | 0.000000           | 0.000000           |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       6 | 0.378661              | 0.000000              | 425.827014         | 0.000000           |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       7 | 0.671518              | 0.000000              | 755.162282         | 0.000000           |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       8 | 0.452400              | 0.000000              | 508.750944         | 0.000000           |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |       9 | 0.000000              | 0.022045              | 0.000000           | 24.790925          |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |      10 | 0.000000              | 0.083533              | 0.000000           | 93.937870          |
| 2019-02-28 00:00:00       |      11 | 0.000000              | 0.896671              | 0.000000           | 1'008.360340       |
+---------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I am stuck at the point where I want to have two base columns and the aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the prettiest solution, but...  I'm using two pivots (one for quantity and one for value) to global temp tables and then join them:

### Table:

```
Create Table #tbl
(
  Dt Date,
  Account Int,
  ISIN VarChar(20),
  Quantity Float,
  Val Float,
  Currency VarChar(3),
  Price Float,
  PriceCHF Float,
  FXRate Float
)
Insert Into #tbl Values
('2019-02-28 00:00:00', 1,'CH5055181629',0.00000000,0.000000,'CHF',1124.56,1124.56,1),
('2019-02-28 00:00:00', 6,'CH5055181629',0.37866100,425.827014,'CHF',1124.56,1124.56,1),
('2019-02-28 00:00:00', 7,'CH5055181629',0.67151800,755.162282,'CHF',1124.56,1124.56,1),
('2019-02-28 00:00:00', 8,'CH5055181629',0.45240000,508.750944,'CHF',1124.56,749.7067,1.5),
('2019-02-28 00:00:00', 9,'CH5055181622',0.02204500,24.790925,'CHF',1124.56,749.7067,1.5),
('2019-02-28 00:00:00',10,'CH5055181622',0.08353300,93.937870,'CHF',1124.56,749.7067,1.5),
('2019-02-28 00:00:00',11,'CH5055181622',0.89667100,1008.360340,'CHF',1124.56,749.7067,1.5)
```

### Pivot 1:

```
SELECT * 
INTO   #assets 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   #tbl) a 

DECLARE @cols1  AS NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @cols1q  AS NVARCHAR(max) 
Declare @query AS NVARCHAR(max); 

SET @cols1 = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(c.ISIN) 
                   FROM   #assets c 
                   FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '' 
            ) 

SET @cols1q = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + 'Cast(ISNULL(##pvt1.' + c.ISIN + ',0) As Decimal(15,6)) As ' + c.ISIN + '_Quantity'
                   FROM   #assets c 
                   FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '' 
)
SET @query = 'SELECT dt, account, ' + @cols1 
             + ' Into ##pvt1 from #assets x pivot ( max(quantity) for ISIN in (' + @cols1 
             + ')) p ' 

EXECUTE(@query)
```

### Pivot 2:

```
SELECT * 
INTO   #assets2 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   #tbl) a 

DECLARE @cols2  AS NVARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @cols2v  AS NVARCHAR(max) 
--        ,@query AS NVARCHAR(max); 

SET @cols2 = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(c.ISIN) 
                   FROM   #assets2 c 
                   FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '' 
            ) 

SET @cols2v = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + 'Cast(ISNULL(##pvt2.' + c.ISIN + ',0) As Decimal(15,6)) As ' + c.ISIN + '_Value' 
                   FROM   #assets2 c 
                   FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '' 
            ) 


SET @query = 'SELECT dt, account, ' + @cols2 
             + ' Into ##pvt2 from #assets x pivot ( sum(val) for ISIN in (' + @cols2 
             + ')) p ' 

EXECUTE(@query)
```

### Join the pivots:

```
Set @query = 

'Select 
       ##pvt1.Dt,
       ##pvt1.Account,' + @cols1q + ', ' + @cols2v +

' From ##pvt1 Inner Join
              ##pvt2 On ##pvt1.Account = ##pvt2.Account
Order By ##pvt1.Account'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Cleanup:

```
Drop Table #assets
Drop Table #assets2
Drop Table ##pvt1
Drop Table ##pvt2
Drop Table #tbl
```

Comment: I rewrote it a little bit, there is no need for two assets tables and there is no need to split the temp table creation into two. I moved it all into a single query that executes Pivot 1, Pivot 2 and joins the pivots. Now, it still misses the aggregation of the values in the rows, i.e. it still shows me too many rows and it doesn't aggregate them per "base column" (i.e. one line per date and account, not one row each per value and quantity column).